# Saving data into two tables at the same time

Tags: php, mysql

I have this code

```
<?php
    include 'dbconnect.php'; ?>
<head>
</head>

<body>
    <form method="post" action="<?php echo $_SERVER["PHP_SELF"]?>">
    <input type="text" name="product_name"/>
    <input type="text" name="product_price" />

        <select name="product_cat">
        <?php
        $results = $connect->query("SELECT * FROM categories ORDER BY cat_name");
            while($row = $results->fetch_array()) {
            extract($row);
            echo "<option value='"."{$cat_name}"."'>"."{$cat_name}"."</option>";
            }  
        $results->free();
        ?>
        </select>

    <input type="submit" name="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
<?php   
    if($_POST){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO products (prd_name, prd_price, cat_id) VALUES(?,?,?)";
    if($stmt = $connect->prepare($sql) )
        {
            $productname = $_POST['product_name'];
            $productprice = $_POST['product_price'];
            $productcat = $_POST['product_cat'];
            $stmt->bind_param("sii", $productname, $productprice, $productcat);
        if($stmt->execute())
            {
                echo "Created";
                $stmt->close();
            }else{
                    die("Unable to create category.");
                }
                }else{
                die("Unable to prepare statement.");
            }
                $connect->close();
            }
        ?>    
</body>
</html>
```

Here the category name is called from a table called categories. You can see the code at the dropdown. Once the user select the category name, fills the product name and product price the form saves the all three data to a table called products.

There is a third table called category_product with two column prd_id and cat_id (product id and category id). I need to record both the id's of product and the category to this table along with this form.

In short, how do i get the category id from the category table when only the name is being echoed and how to know the last saved id of the product and then inserting both the records into the second(category_products) tables at the same time.

Comment: first of all, i'd use <option value='"."{$cat_id}"."'>"."{$cat_name}"."</option> so you have you catId. Then for the last insert id, use mysqli_insert_id that will return the id of the last query insert

Comment: @Psychokiller1888 okay. Ill try and then get back to you. Thank you for advising.

Answer (score 1):

You can get the [insert_id](http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.insert-id.php) from your first statement to use in the second. Here's some pseudo code to help you with that

```
if($stmt->execute()) {
     $record_id = $stmt->insert_id;
     $sql = "INSERT table2(data, table1_id) VALUES($someval, $record_id)";
     // Run the query here
}
```

Comment: thank you sir, but how do I get the id for the category name?.

Comment: By passing it as i wrote in my comment above